FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified (telegram-bot)
Im trying to make this script run on telegram which works fine until i send a picture to the bot and it gives me this error.
I am trying to run this script:
import os
import subprocess
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext

# Replace 'TOKEN' with your actual Telegram bot token
TOKEN = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    update.message.reply_text('Send me a picture and I will change its metadata!')

def handle_photo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    # Get photo file ID
    photo = update.message.photo[-1]
    photo_file = context.bot.get_file(photo.file_id)

    # Download photo
    photo_file.download('temp.jpg')

    # Change metadata
    metadata_changes = {'Title': 'New Title', 'Description': 'New Description'}
    change_metadata('temp.jpg', metadata_changes)

    # Send the modified photo back
    update.message.reply_photo(open('temp.jpg', 'rb'))

def change_metadata(image_path, metadata_changes):
    """
    Change metadata of an image file.

    Args:
    - image_path (str): Path to the image file.
    - metadata_changes (dict): Dictionary containing metadata changes.
                              Example: {'Title': 'New Title', 'Description': 'New Description'}
    """
    # Build the command to change metadata using exiftool
    command = ['exiftool']
    for key, value in metadata_changes.items():
        command.extend(['-'+key+'='+value])
    command.append(image_path)

    # Execute the command
    try:
        subprocess.run(command, check=True)
        print("Metadata changed successfully.")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print("Error:", e)

def main() -> None:
    updater = Updater(TOKEN)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.photo & ~Filters.command, handle_photo))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


but when i try to run PS C:\Users\User\telegram-bot> python telegram_metadata_bot.py i keep getting this error (after a dozen lines of code processes):
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

"temp.jpg" is inside the "telegram-bot" folder and so is the exiftool executable file and the extra files i extracted.
i have Python 3.12.3 installed and im running this script on terminal with adminstrator permission.
how do i solve this issue? im new to running scripts and coding so i apologize if this is a dumb question.
i tried googling this issue but none helped me

Please extract a [mcve] and provide a full backtrace. Also important, check that the file is there and check that the path to the file is correct, for relative paths that requires checking the current working directory.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
